# Kohana - $this->request->uri($params) alternative in 3.2

Tags: kohana

Is there any alternative for getting uri with changed parameter as $this->request->uri($params) in KO 3.2?

Example:

```
//Kohana 3.1 ; current uri = articles/show/10 (<controller>/<action>/<id>)

$this->request->uri(array('id' => 11)); // return 'articles/show/11'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 3.2 there is no "short" way for this, because now `$this->request->uri()` returns current URI. Use `$this->request->route()->uri()` with all params you need:

```
$params  = array('id' => 11); // what params you want to change
$params += $this->request->param(); // current request params
$params += array(
    // note that $this->request->param() doesnt contain directory/controller/action values!
   'directory' => $this->request->directory(),
   'controller' => $this->request->controller(),
   'action' => $this->request->action(),
);
$uri = $this->request->route()->uri($params);
```

Of course, you can create a special method for this (something like `$this->request->old_uri(array('id' => 11))`).

Here is an [issue link](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/3690) for that API change.

Comment: It's pity. It was much shorter. :( I'll probably create special method as you said. thx